# Parse JSON nested array in Java (with dictionary?)

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm having trouble parsing some JSON in a java application.

The JSON format is as follows:

```
{"values": [["kevin", "a value"], ["another name", "another value"]], "cols":["name", "val"]}
```

My code to parse it this ("results" contains the raw JSON string):

```
JSONObject myobj = new JSONObject(results);
JSONArray json = myobj.getJSONArray("values");

for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){

    JSONArray tmpArr = json.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("values");

    for(int j = 0; j < tmpArr.length(); j++){
        System.out.println(tmpArr.getJSONObject(j).toString());
    }
}
```

This is giving me a JSON typeMismatch error.

My end goal is to be able to use this JSON method that I'm used to working with to get individual values out of my data:

```
jsonObject.getString("name");
```

Where name would be the column/attribute name specified in the "cols" in the JSON string.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: There is no element named "Value".

Comment: @HotLicks the "Value" was a typo sorry, it should've been "values". So there's no way to deal with this? I was under the impression that it's some sort of dictionary.

Comment: Why are you getting "values" twice.  The second one is going to go wanting, I think.

Comment: You've got an object with two entries -- "values" and "cols".  The "values" and "cols" entries are, in turn, arrays.  "values" is an array containing two arrays.  "cols" contains just two strings.

Comment: @HotLicks So if I just do JSONArray json = myObj.getJSONArray("Values"), "json" should now contain the array of ["kevin", "a value"], ["another name", "another value"].

Is there a way to map these nested arrays into objects by using jsonObject.getString("name") since the data mappings are declared in the "cols" object?

Comment: Use a [JSON online parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to better visualize the data.

Comment: `myObj.getJSONArray("values")` -- case is significant.  And there is no "name" object element anywhere -- the "name" you see is a simple string.

Comment: First check your object with isArray() method.:) it will return its correct format array or not...

Comment: @HotLicks I see what you mean when I used the visualizer- the column names are just another array of simple strings. What I'm trying to do is get the json into an arraylist of objects with 2 attributes (name, value). It's throwing me off that it's "values":[["kevin", "a value"],["another name", "another value"]] as I'm used to seeing [{"name":"kevin,"value":"a value"},{"name":"another name","value":"another value"}]

Comment: So it looks like I can't access the individual attributes by using jsonObject.getString("field name") since it's not encapsulated into a json "object" using {} and specifying fields using {"name":"kevin", "value":"a value"}. The way I'm going about it is using jsonArray.optJSONArray(i).getString(1)) where "i" is a for loop iterating through the array and "1" represents the field "name" since it's typed as an array and not a {object}. Thanks for the help @HotLicks it was honestly very helpful